# Why does an iframe of equal size cause parent div to scroll?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'd simply like to know why an iframe with 100% height and a size (according to web inspector) equal to parent causes a scroll bar to appear.

I found a few questions regarding this topic and though there seem to be workarounds, but so far I've yet to see any explanation about why this happens.

To be absolutely clear:  **I am not looking for a solution**.  My question is about ***why*** this happens.  It seems to be consistent across browsers I've tried so I'm assuming there are web standards somewhere which account for this seemingly odd behavior.

```css
#content {
  height: 90vh;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the iframe that produces the scrollbar, it's the whitespace after it

If you don't want to see it, use

```
* { line-height: 0; }
```

If it doesn't work try adding

```
iframe { display: block; }
```

too. Iframes are rendered as inline elements by default (iframe = 'inline frame'), and thus, have a line-height which causes the issue.

Comment: son of a gun, you are absolutely spot on.  I've been scratching my head about this for a while now.  Odd thing is, if it was white space after, I'd think removing white space in the html would take care of it but it doesn't (i.e. `<div class="wrapper"><iframe></iframe></div>` doesn't fix it) thank you

Comment: it's funny that none of the existing answers i found mention this - everyone just says use `overflow: hidden` which sheds zero light on the reason why